# Run 2 files at the same time and minimize them as batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to run a file (virus.bat) and then a PowerPoint presentation (presentation.pptx). I want to run virus.bat minimized and then presentation.pptx but not minimized. I tried to write the following code, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

```
start /min virus.bat start presentation.pptx exit
```

Comment: Can you at the very least show the code you have tried, as per your comment _" I tryed to write this code"_ ?

Comment: try `start "" /min virus.bat && start presentation.pptx && exit`

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer @Road_to_BigStar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```bat
start /min virus.bat & start /max presentation.pptx & exit
```

There is also an option which you can use: `/wait`. This, will wait until a process file is closed.

You can check `start /?` for more information.